# How can I activate a specific datapoint in an ReCharts Area Chart?

Tags: javascript, recharts, area-chart

I have an AreaChart (actually a ComposedChart with an Area and a Line) and I would like to display a tooltip over one of the data points after the chart renders. Works great if I mouseover the chart, but I want it to display on render. For a PieChart I can do this via the ActiveSlice and set the slice I want to be active, then handle it in there, but for Area Charts I can't find a way.

I am actually using a Custom Tooltip and so could do this myself if I could get access to the internal data points that are created when the chart renders, but can't find a way to get at them (I was hoping they might be passed into onAnimationEnd, but no luck).

Any pointers appreciated!